# Nested routes in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a routing scheme where `#/articles` leads to the `articles.html` view, and `#/articles/featured` leads to `featured.html`. I'm not sure how to declare this nested writing, though. If I configure my routes as follows, both `#/articles` and `#/articles/featured` leads to `articles.html` (since both paths match r'^articles').

```dart
library my_router;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

class MyRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {
  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    router.root
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'articles',
          path: '/articles',
          enter: view('views/articles.html'),
          mount: (Route route) => route
            ..addRoute(
                name: 'featured',
                path: '/featured',
                enter: view('views/featured.html'))

      );
  }
}
```

If I omit the `enter: view('views/articles.html')` line, the `#/articles/featured` route correctly routes to `featured.html`, but then nothing routes to `articles.html`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define nested views it's expected that they will be rendered by nested `ng-view`s, but it doesn't seem like what you really want. Your workaround by using a flat structure may be OK. Alternatively you could do something like this:

```dart
class MyRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {
  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    router.root
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'articles',
          path: '/articles',
          mount: (Route route) => route
            ..addRoute(
                name: 'all',
                path: '/all',
                default: true,
                enter: view('views/articles.html')
            ..addRoute(
                name: 'featured',
                path: '/featured',
                enter: view('views/featured.html'))
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you rework the example using nested `ng-view`s

Comment: @pavelgj I have only one ng-view in the homepage. Although the route is nested logically they are not rendered by nested ng-views. So, how should my router look like. Is it advisable to have a nested structure in the router or should I go for a flat structure? [The question is about the best practice assuming both the method works good in this scenario]

Answer (score 3):

I can get this to work by avoiding `mount` and defining the routes from specific to general, but the solution seems clunky and error prone. The correct way is to use `mount` and to properly nest the routes, but I cannot get that to work. Meanwhile, here is a temporary solution:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

class MyRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {
  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    router.root
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'featured',
          path: '/articles/featured',
          enter: view('views/featured.html'))
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'articles',
          path: '/articles',
          enter: view('views/articles.html'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this duplicated "/articles" path prefix trigger multiple matches so that no routing takes place?

Comment: The routes are matched in order. So, '/articles/featured' maps to 'views/featured.html', and '/articles' maps to 'views/articles.html'. I would recommend the accepted answer as the way to go, though.